# How is the formula for partition of a set derived.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

[image]

I don't understand how we get from the first step to the second step.  I understand that it would be the product of all of the subsets, but I don't understand the simplification that is made thereafter

Comment: The second factor in the denominator of each binomial coefficient cancels the numerator of the next binomial coefficient.  The exception is the final binomial coefficient, where the second factor in the denominator equals 0!. (For some reason, in the quoted text this last factor is written as the first factor rather than the second in the final binomial coefficient.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re starting with

$$\binom{n}{n_1}\binom{n-n_1}{n_2}\binom{n-n_1-n_2}{n_3}\ldots\binom{n-n_1-\ldots-n_{r-1}}{n_r}\;.\tag{1}$$

In general $\dbinom{n}k=\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$, so a typical factor in $(1)$ is

$$\binom{n-n_1-\ldots-n_m}{n_{m+1}}=\frac{(n-n_1-\ldots-n_m)!}{n_{m+1}!\color{brown}{(n-n_1-\ldots-n_m-n_{m+1})!}}\;,\tag{2}$$

and $(1)$ is equal to

$$\frac{n!}{n_1!(n-n_1)!}\cdot\frac{(n-n_1)!}{n_2!(n-n_1-n_2)!}\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{(n-n_1-\ldots-n_{r-1})!}{n_r!(n-n_1-\ldots-n_r)!}\;.\tag{3}$$

Notice that the brown factor $\color{brown}{(n-n_1-\ldots-n_m-n_{m+1})!}$ in the denominator of the fraction in $(2)$ is the numerator of the next factor in $(1)$, which is

$$\binom{n-n_1-\ldots-n_m-n_{m+1}}{n_{m+2}}=\frac{\color{brown}{(n-n_1-\ldots-n_m-n_{m+1})!}}{n_{m+2}!(n-n_1-n_2-\ldots-n_m-n_{m+1}-n_{m+2})!}\;.$$

Thus, every numerator in $(3)$ except the first one, $n!$, cancels with the second factorial in the previous denominator: the second numerator, $(n-n_1)!$, cancels with the $(n-n_1)!$ in the first denominator, the third numerator, $n-n_1-n_2)!$, cancels with the second factorial in the second denominator, and so on. The only things that don’t cancel are the first numerator, $n!$, the first factorials in each denominator, and the second factorial in the last denominator. Thus, the product $(3)$ collapses to

$$\frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!n_3!\ldots n_r!(n-n_1-\ldots-n_r)!}\;,\tag{4}$$

and since $n_1+n_2+\ldots+n_r=n$, $$(n-n_1-n_2-\ldots-n_r)!=0!=1\;,$$

and $(4)$ turns out to be just

$$\frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!n_3!\ldots n_r!}\;.$$